# How to change datagridview button text on cell value basis?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView placed on a Windows Form and a Button inside the datagridview.
Now I want to change the text of a button on cell value basis.

How can i do it?

Comment: More information may be needed.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484810/changing-datagridviewbuttoncolumns-button-text-per-row

Answer (score 3):

cast the Cell as a DataGridViewButtonCell and use it as you wish..

```
var BtnCell = (DataGridViewButtonCell)YourDataGridView.Rows[yourindex].Cells[cellindex];
BtnCell.Value = "New Button Value";
```

Comment: ERROR Occured  :-Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell'.

Comment: You need to point your cell index to the correct index of your ButtonCell. It looks like your using the index of a textboxcell.....

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

You can set `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` property value of true displays to the Text property value on the cells button.